# Created batch folders on LAMP server but can't be accessed

Tags: php, html, apache, lamp

Sorry for interrupting, I was trying to create batch folders using PHP codes on my LAMP server. My codes is attached below:

```
enter code here


<?php

 **//sample .html template** 

 $out1 = 
 "<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    GGYY der 
  </body>
  </html>";

 **//fetch folder names from .txt file under my website main directory**

 $file_name="DirName.txt";
 $fp=fopen($file_name,'r');
 $content = array();
 $i =0;
 while(!feof($fp)){ 
 $buffer=fgets($fp,4096);
 $content[$i]=$buffer;
 $i++;
 }

 **//create folders base on $content size**

 for($j=0; $j<sizeof($content); $j++){
   if(mkdir($content[$j],0777))
     echo "folder created"."<br>";
   else
     echo "fail to create"."<br>";

 **//create a .html file in created folder** 
 $mycat  = fopen ("./$content[$j]/mycat.html","w");

 **//use copy template into mycat.html** 
 fwrite($mycat, $out1);
 fclose ($mycat);
 echo "Success";    
 }
 fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

Based on my codes, it seems like that I did created several folders at one click, but when I try to access these folders through SSH FTP connection, it shows that "Directory /xxx/www/xxx/Aquarius : no such file or directory"
Even if there are folder icons on that directory.

And I tried to connect to my server through Ubuntu command line, cd to that dedicate directory and enter ls command,
It shows that all folders I just created with "??" mark right after the folders name.
And I can't either delete the folder or access the folder.

I already spend all day on this and can't find an answer.
It'll be really appreciated if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Please add the contents (or parts of anyway) of DirName.txt.  I suspect you have hidden chars in there that make the dire names mess up.  Probably `\r\n` if that file was created on Windows.    A `trim()` of each line before creating the folder might be a good fix.  Now to delete directories with weird names, look into `ls -i` to show the inode number, and `find -inum <NUMBER> -exec rmdir {} \;` to flush them out.

Comment: @Nic3550 Suggestion worked for me, after I use trim() before creating the folder, problem solved! I think you are right about creating .txt file under Windows, it cause problem, I should avoid this next time. Thank you for help a lot !!

Comment: I copied my comment into the answer field, I would appreciate if you accepted it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have hidden chars in there that make the dire names mess up. Probably \r\n if that file was created on Windows.

A trim() of each line before creating the folder might be a good fix.

Now to delete directories with weird names, look into `ls -i` to show the inode number, and `find -inum <NUMBER> -exec rmdir {} \;` to flush them out.